# Excel - put together the element the elements of different lists in the same column

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I have two (or more) lists with different and variable number of elements in excel.
I was looking for a way, without using VBA, to automatically put them in the same column.

i.e.
starting from  three lists in different columns

```
A={KPI1;KPI2;KPI3}
```

`B={KPI14;KPI25;KPI36;KPI45}`

`C={KPI42;KPI51;KPI67;KPI82;KPI99;KPI125}`

I would like to find a concatenation of formulas to get in a different column something like:

`D={KPI1;KPI2;KPI3;KPI14;KPI25;KPI36;KPI45;KPI42;KPI51;KPI67;KPI82;KPI99;KPI125}`

I have the impression that counting the lines in each of the columns and with a good array formulation it should be possible bu I did not manage :(.

I want to use the formulas to have the whole dynamically changing I.e if someone add something to the column S the column T is automatically update.

Many Thanks for your help!

Comment: What may be changed? What is not changed? If number of data and cells where data placed are chenged without rule, there is no safe (not be over-written) cell for placing a formula. Code of VBA is not placed on cells, so this formula placing problem never occure.

Comment: I would like to put the same formula in the whole column. And let the the formula itself see from what list picking the datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have it understood right, you want to get the content of the cells in the columns A, B and C together in column D if they are not empty.

If so, then the following could help:

```
    A     B      C       D
1 KPI1  KPI14   KPI42   KPI1
2 KPI2  KPI25   KPI51   KPI2
3 KPI3  KPI36   KPI67   KPI3
4       KPI45   KPI82   KPI14
5               KPI99   KPI25
6               KPI125  KPI36
7                       KPI45
8                       KPI42
9                       KPI51
10                      KPI67
11                      KPI82
12                      KPI99
13                      KPI125
14                      #WERT!


Formula in D1:

{=INDEX($A$1:$C$20,
MID(
SMALL(IF($A$1:$C$20<>"",--(COLUMN($A$1:$C$20)&ROW($A$1:$C$20)),9^99),ROW(A1))
,2,17),
LEFT(
SMALL(IF($A$1:$C$20<>"",--(COLUMN($A$1:$C$20)&ROW($A$1:$C$20)),9^99),ROW(A1))
,1))}
```

The formula is an array formula. But since you mentioned array formulas in your question, you seem to know what this is.

You can fill the formula down until the #VALUE error occurs.

Greetings

Axel